# How to handle Automapper Exceptions (try/catch)

Tags: c#, automapper

There are **[two types](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tree/develop/src/AutoMapper)** of exceptions in Automapper and I can´t find information anywhere on how to use them.

The exceptions are
    **AutoMapperMappingException**
and
    **AutoMapperConfigurationException**

*Does anybody know the difference of these two and how I should set up try/catch for them?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper%20source%20code.).

**AutoMapperConfigurationException** is used when the mapping profiles are loaded up by AutoMapper. Its thrown my Automapper when performing a configuration checks.

```
    [Test]
    public void Mapper_AssertConfigurationIsValid_Expect_No_Exceptions()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
```

**AutoMapperMappingException** is used during "runtime"...that is when the actual mapping code is run to turn your source dto to your destination dto.

HTH.

Comment: So you would never use AssertConfigurationIsValid except in unittests? So in my code I would always try/catch on AutoMapperMappingException and that would basicly catch the same thing?

Comment: Thats right -  AssertConfigurationIsValid only in tests. Also I never catch "AutoMapperMappingException" - its not something that is expected or we know how to handle. Your case may be different.